# Import file in python program under Unix

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, unix, aix

Below Code is printing output in diff lines . I want like -->200 but its showing in diff line..

```
with open('URL.txt','r') as f:


    for url in f:
        print url  ## Printing URL with line gap
        ret = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        print url,"-->",ret.code
```

Output :

```
http://www.gogle.com
--> 200
http://yahoo.com --> 200
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Here is a snippet. Here  I can check one URL . I want to import multiple no. of urls from one file and will use loop to check each website.

url='https://www.google.com' ; 
    code=urllib.urlopen(url).getcode() ;
            **#here getcode is working ;
            print url,"-------->", code

Comment: Edit the question to include the code you've tried and an explanation of what did not work. You can read files using the `open` function.

Answer (score 1):

This will iterate over the lines of a file. Assumed that each line is a url, it will call your function for each url.

```
import urllib2
with open('URL.txt','r') as f:
    for url in f:
        ret = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        print("%s --> %s" % (url.strip(), ret.code))
```

EDIT: added `strip()` for correct output

Comment: I just edited my original question with the snippet code and the issue . Can you please check once.